# Passing jquery function as variable parameter to the custom function

Tags: jquery, function, height, width, argument-passing

I am writing a function which calculates the biggest height / width and makes the elements of the same height / width. I want to pass 2 parameters to this function:

```
1. The selector, which can be(element, class )
2. jQuery `width()` / `height()` function
```

and the desired result should be the function which looks like..

```
Eg 1. equalDimensions('.class', width() ); OR
Eg 2. equalDimensions( div, height() );
```

and based on what is passed to the function `width()` / `height()` it will calculate the biggest height / width and make all the selectors which is passed as a first parameter equal width / height.

Being new to jQuery, I am struggling with putting it into code.

This is what I have tried so far...

```
var equalDimension = function(  selector,  fn ){
    var dimension = fn();
    var biggestDimemsion = 0;
    $(selector).each(function(){
        if($(this).dimension > biggestDimemsion){
            biggestDimemsion = $(this).dimension;
        }
    });
    $(selector).each(function(){
        $(this).dimension(biggestDimemsion);
    });
};
```

Comment: At the moment I am using two separate custom functions for getting equal height & width by just passing selector as an arguments and it works fine, But it would be great to create just one function and passing width/ height function as a second argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a quick example of how I would approach this problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/3NRah/

```
var equalDimension = function (selector, fn) {
    var $elements = $(selector),
        dimensions = $elements.map(function (i) {
            return $elements.eq(i)[fn]();
        }),
        maxDimension = Math.max.apply(Math, dimensions);
    $elements[fn](maxDimension);
};

equalDimension('div', 'height');
```

This assumes that you are passing the name of a jQuery function, rather than the function itself.  If you want to pass the actual function, it would look like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/3NRah/1/

```
var equalDimension = function (selector, fn) {
    var $elements = $(selector),
        dimensions = $elements.map(function (i) {
            return fn.call($elements.eq(i));
        }),
        maxDimension = Math.max.apply(Math, dimensions);
    fn.call($elements, maxDimension);
};

equalDimension('div', $.fn.height);
```

---

Edit: In terms of creating a clean UI for this, I would most-likely add this as in the following JSBin.

http://jsbin.com/pogujozane/edit?js,output

```
$.fn.equalDimension = function (fn) {
    var $elements = $(this),
        dimensions = $elements.map(function (i) {
            return $elements.eq(i)[fn]();
        }),
        maxDimension = Math.max.apply(Math, dimensions);
    $elements[fn](maxDimension);
};
$.fn.equalHeight = function () {
  return $(this).equalDimension('height');
};
$.fn.equalWidth = function () {
  return $(this).equalDimension('width');
}
```

So that it could be called like:

```
$('div').equalHeight();
```

Comment: Much cleaner than my (now-deleted) answer.

Comment: Brilliant. Both your solutions works perfect. Thank you Robert. Just want to know from jQuery point of view  which one is a better approach, using a string or a function as a parameter and if why (If you can please explain the reason)

Comment: I'm not really sure if one is better than the other - but I do think the error you get will be a bit more obvious with the second solution - it just requires that you know where the jQuery functions live.

Comment: I added a cleaner solution that is closer to how I would approach this.

Answer (score 0):

You should really pass a sting instead of a function and do somthine like this :

```
var equalDimension = function(  selector,  fn ){
    var dimension = fn === 'width' ? 'width' : 'height'; //Prevent from runing any other jQuery functions
    var biggestDimemsion = 0;
    $(selector).each(function(){
        if($(this)[dimension]() > biggestDimemsion){
            biggestDimemsion = $(this).dimension;
        }
    });
    $(selector).each(function(){
        $(this)[dimension](biggestDimemsion);
    });
};

equalDimension('selector', 'width');
```

Side note, the second each can be ignored :

```
var equalDimension = function(  selector,  fn ){
    var dimension = fn === 'width' ? 'width' : 'height'; //Prevent from runing any other jQuery functions
    var biggestDimemsion = 0;
    $(selector).each(function(){
        if($(this)[dimension]() > biggestDimemsion){
            biggestDimemsion = $(this).dimension;
        }
    });
    $(selector)[dimension](biggestDimemsion);
};
```